# Apple paid application mechanism

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I know this is a silly question, But I want to just know about it.

How iPhone paid application is work ?

for example -: If I have download one paid application form apple store than after a year do we need to re-download that app or i'll be continue as it is?

Please help me to understand this thing.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you dont have re-download your app again, it will be there unless you delete it from your device, but if you download agin it will be downloaded without paying any money if download it with same apple id.